# Paypal refund using uc_paypal.modue in drupal with API

Tags: php, button, paypal, drupal

drupal has a module called uc_paypal.module which has this part of the code.

```
// Sends a request to PayPal and returns a response array.
function uc_paypal_api_request($request, $server) {
  $request['USER'] = variable_get('uc_paypal_api_username', '');
  $request['PWD'] = variable_get('uc_paypal_api_password', '');
  $request['VERSION'] = '3.0';
  $request['SIGNATURE'] = variable_get('uc_paypal_api_signature', '');

  $data = '';
  foreach ($request as $key => $value) {
    $data .= $key .'='. urlencode(ereg_replace(',', '', $value)) .'&';
  }
  $data = substr($data, 0, -1);

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $server);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,0);
  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  if ($error = curl_error($ch)) {
    watchdog('uc_paypal', $error, WATCHDOG_ERROR);
  }
  curl_close($ch);

  return _uc_paypal_nvp_to_array($response);
```

}

What I would like to do is create a link button that can refund a completed order.

I found this API code example.

```
curl -v -X POST https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/payments/captures/2GG279541U471931P/refund \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer <Access-Token>" \
-H "PayPal-Request-Id: 123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440020" \
-d '{
  "amount": {
    "value": "10.00",
    "currency_code": "USD"
  },
  "invoice_id": "INVOICE-123",
  "note_to_payer": "DefectiveProduct",
  "payment_instruction": {
    "platform_fees": [
      {
        "amount": {
          "currency_code": "USD",
          "value": "1.00"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}'
```

What I would like to do is load the data from the database using this code to get the TxnId for the order.

```
$result = db_query("SELECT order_id, txn_id 
FROM uc_payment_paypal_ipn WHERE status = 'Completed' AND uid = %d AND order_id = %d", $uid, $order->order_id);
```

And join all three items into one PHP call to Paypal to refund the order.
I just don't know how to join those codes together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code example is for the current REST API, which uses a clientid and secret for authentication to first obtain an access token.

The uc_paypal.module uses the much older (15+ years) classic NVP API, which authenticates with a USER, PWD, SIGNATURE.

It's generally not a good idea to mix very old and current APIs. [Here's the API reference](https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/refund-transaction-nvp/) for a classic API RefundTransaction call.

Comment: how would I formulate the syntax code to achieve the result of a refund? The link above provided only parameter fields. With no example of a full syntax code.

Comment: See the first code block in you question